# How to display a variable in a template?

Tags: vue.js

**drf**

```
class ShipmentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Shipment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ShipmentSerializer

    def get_renderer_context(self):
        context = super().get_renderer_context()
        action = self.action

        if (action == 'retrieve'):
            context['shipments'] = Shipment.objects.all()
        elif (action == 'list'):
            context['foo'] = 'bar'
        return context
```

**vue.js**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Shipments list</h1>
        {{ foo }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import $ from 'jquery'

    export default {
        name: "shipment_list",
        created() {
            this.loadShipments()
        },
        methods: {
            post_create() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8001/shipments/',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {},
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    success: (response) => {
                        console.log(response)
                    },
                    error: (response) =>
                        console.log(response)
                })
            },
            loadShipments() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8001/shipments/',
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    success: (response) => {
                        console.log(response)
                    },
                    error: (response) => {
                        console.log('error')
                        console.log(response)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

I need to display the `foo` variable in the `template`. To do this, I overridden the `get_renderer_context` method and the variable is there. But when rendering the page I get `error`

> Property or method "foo" is not defined on the instance but
>   referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive,
>   either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
>   initializing the property.

Also I get next `response`

```
{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
abort: ƒ ( statusText )
always: ƒ ()
catch: ƒ ( fn )
done: ƒ ()
fail: ƒ ()
getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ ()
getResponseHeader: ƒ ( key )
overrideMimeType: ƒ ( type )
pipe: ƒ ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ )
progress: ƒ ()
promise: ƒ ( obj )
readyState: 4
setRequestHeader: ƒ ( name, value )
state: ƒ ()
status: 200
statusCode: ƒ ( map )
statusText: "load"
then: ƒ ( onFulfilled, onRejected, onProgress )
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. You are talking about `foo`, but `foo` is not referenced in the template, and the error you are quoting is about the `shipments` variable.

Comment: Sry. Updated code.

Comment: It's totally unrelated to Django (tags fixed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining `foo` in your python but not in your Vue file. You need to set `foo` equal to the response you get from your ajax call in your JS file.

define `foo` in your data section in your VUE file.

```
data() {
 return {
   foo: null,
 }
}
```

then in your ajax call....

```
this.foo = response.data;
```

This will work. Take a look at the Vue docs and those will help a lot!